# Trouble with car paint material only applied on the left side

Tags: modeling, materials, shaders

I'm having trouble with the material, the car paint only applied on the left side. I already assign and recalculate normals, but nothing happened

[image: the materials only appear in the left side. For the others, it only appear inside. I already try to recalculate normals, but nothing happened]

Comment: how did you unwrap? maybe check your UV in the UV Editor. Or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I already share the blend file, thanks

Comment: you need to share the URL link it will give you

Comment: oh yeah sorry, here's the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/2fcabc8c47a244df984bcb91ccd654c7 But i think that's the light issue, but i still don't know why the material only clearly reflected in some faces, not all.

Comment: on what material are you painting? there is no Image Texture in the material called "another_car_paint". Also you haven't unwrapped your object

Comment: on the "Plane" object. Yes i dont use any image texture. I already unwrap it before, but nothing happend, so I give the file that i save before i unwrap it

Comment: Yes i knew it, but i don't want to paint, i just want to see the reflection of the material, but as you can see. The reflection only show at the left side and inside, i think the problem its on the material itself or on the hdri light.

Comment: I've loaded my own HDRI as you didn't pack yours, and it seems to work fine here, I can see the reflection on both the left and right sides: https://zupimages.net/up/21/40/iz84.gif

Comment: Yeah right, I think the problem its on the hdri light. When i change it, its looked fine :) thank you very muchh

Comment: Texture scale 1 and clip or bigger texture scale and repeat should work.

Answer (score 0):

goto edit mode . select the faces , where you want to have car-paint. in the material window select the car-paint material and click the "assign" button.

Comment: Already, but its still same, the material only appear inside

Comment: try this: edit mode (select all faces) / mesh / normals / recalculate outside